# How to pare JSON file starts with b'"

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am getting this string when we read s3 object as JSON

```
json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
print(json_object)
jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
```

The data looks like this when i printed

```
raw = b'"[{\\"timestamp\\": \\"2022-07-27T12:34:52.304000+00:00\\", \\"type\\": \\"ExecutionSucceeded\\", \\"id\\": 9, \\"previousEventId\\": 8, \\"executionSucceededEventDetails\\": {\\"output\\": \\"{\\\\\\"statusCode\\\\\\":200,\\\\\\"body\\\\\\":\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Hello from Lambda!\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\"}\\", \\"outputDetails\\": {\\"truncated\\": false}}}]"'
```

I want to extract type out of it .

But when i do it i get error

```
    status=data[0]['type']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My code

```
raw = b'"[{\\"timestamp\\": \\"2022-07-27T12:34:52.304000+00:00\\", \\"type\\": \\"ExecutionSucceeded\\", \\"id\\": 9, \\"previousEventId\\": 8, \\"executionSucceededEventDetails\\": {\\"output\\": \\"{\\\\\\"statusCode\\\\\\":200,\\\\\\"body\\\\\\":\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Hello from Lambda!\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\"}\\", \\"outputDetails\\": {\\"truncated\\": false}}}]"'

data = json.loads(raw.decode('utf-8'))

print(data)
print(data[0])
status=data[0]['type']
print(status)
```

Comment: What did this print for `data[0]`?

Comment: @ScottHunter  It prints `[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your decoded `raw` represents a *string*, not a json object (notice that the first and last characters of `raw` are quotes `"`).

When you do `data = json.loads(raw.decode('utf-8'))`, you have `type(data) == str`, i.e. `data` is the string `"[{\\"timestamp\\": \\"2022-..."`, which happens to itself be a json string.

To deserialize this string, `json.loads` it again:

```
data = json.loads(data)
```

And now use it:

```
print(data[0]['type'])
# prints ExecutionSucceeded
```